# PHP - strange issue - corrupted headers/content due to seemingly unrelated code line

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, httpresponse, httpwebresponse

I have spent 3 days & 4 SO questions trying to fix something which didn't have a problem in the first place. However, the actual problem now has me stumped.  Please see the following curl code. It correctly fetches a particular webpage and displays. There is a commented line (no. 8), which sets an additional POST variable. If I uncomment it, then the browser tries to download a gzip file instead of displaying it.  I don't know the correlation between that line and the strange behaviour at all.

(Note: I have used a static url from w3schools so others can try this code. I am trying to use this code for my own internal data server and proxy, and am facing exactly same issue. Uncommenting that particular line results in the strange behaviour. I need to use this variable.  I don't presently know a work-around plus am very curious to find the cause).

```
<?php
session_start();

$i_var_prefix="i_var_";

// Other important client dependent 'SERVER' variables.
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) { $_POST["${i_var_prefix}_HTTPS"]=$_SERVER['HTTPS']; };
//if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) { $_POST["${i_var_prefix}_REMOTE_ADDR"]=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; };
// STRANGE PROBLEM:: IF I UNCOMMENT THE LINE ABOVE, THEN THE BROWSER DOES NOT DISPLAY THE CONTENT BUT TRIES TO DOWNLOAD IT.

$curl_url="http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/form_action.asp";


// Set values of these header variables as got from client
$field_array= array(
      'Accept' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT',
      'Accept-Charset' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET',
      'Accept-Encoding' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING',
      'Accept-Language' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE',
      'Connection' => 'HTTP_CONNECTION',
      'Host' => 'HTTP_HOST',
      'Referer' => 'HTTP_REFERER',
      'User-Agent' => 'HTTP_USER_AGENT'
      );

$curl_request_headers=array();

foreach ($field_array as $key => $value) {
   if(isset($_SERVER["$value"])) {
      $server_value=$_SERVER["$value"];
      $curl_request_headers[]="$key: $server_value";
   }
};

//------
session_write_close();

//Open connection
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_COOKIE,session_name()."=".session_id().";");
//Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_request_headers);


//Execute post
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);

//Close connection
curl_close($curl_handle);

list($headers,$content)=explode("\r\n\r\n",$result,2);
foreach (explode("\r\n",$headers) as $hdr) {
   header($hdr);
}
echo $content;
?>
```

### UPDATE:

With the line uncommented, the result headers received are:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Date: Wed, 22 Dec 2010 14:32:43 GMT
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
> MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> Content-Length: 478
> Content-Type: text/html
> Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSASCDCDT=KIIKANGALGLDJMLFHGPJBBOM; path=/
> Cache-control: private
> ```

With the line commented out, result headers are:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Date: Wed, 22 Dec 2010 14:34:21 GMT
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
> MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> Content-Length: 478
> Content-Type: text/html
> Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSASCDCDT=JLPKANGAHDCNADBMNGHGIMCO; path=/
> Cache-control: private
> ```

1) Why the difference?

2) How to handle the continue thing correctly?

---

### SUMMARY:

The reason was that with that line, the number of POST variables increased to more than 1 and curl started automatically sending "Expect:" in header. This made the server respond with "Continue" header, which I was not handling. 
I am using the solution posted below. The comments, specially Mchl's comments -  were very helpful in getting me in the right direction as I had no clue how that line could affect the behaviour.

regards,

JP

Comment: Is that line throwing an error that's causing the headers to not be sent?

Comment: I have tried moving the line to various parts of the file, that didnt help.

Comment: Check how uncommenting this line affect `$headers` variable.

Comment: I can't see any errors reported. I have used ini_set('display_errors', 1); If I download the file and uncompress it - it has the proper contents (with headers) and no errors either.

Comment: @Mchl: Great suggestion. I tried. They change. I will post the results. I have no clue why they change and what to do to fix.

Comment: I just ran your script and got the same result, "Input was received as: Nothing", from both commented and uncommented versions. No download behaviour.  This was with PHP5.3.4 on Solaris10.  What version PHP are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one solution through some guesswork and searching. From http://matthom.com/archive/2008/12/29/php-curl-disable-100-continue-expectation. The 100-continue status is "expected" by default when using cURL-

`Expect: 100-continue`.

I disabled it using

`$curl_request_headers[]="Expect: ";`.

And now it works! (I guess server stops sending the continue header). (However, I am not convinced this is robust for all types of requests that the client can make [in the long run] but might be okay for normal purpose).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously uncommenting this line changes the `$result` you get from `curl_exec`.

You have two curl options you need to examine:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
```

[edit]

A quick fix might be to remove the HTTP 100 header from $headers.

Comment: I didn't expect the result to change because that POST field is ignored by my backend server scripts - and very likely the static url I am using (indeed the content does not change - only there is an extra "continue" header). Can you explain how can I 'examine' the options and debug? Definitely the count and $_POST array have changed.

Comment: This one field certeainly infliences `count($_POST)`, so that's something you might want to check.

Comment: Yes, that fix might be correct. Also see another fix I found and posted.

Comment: Anyway, CURL_POST shoud be a boolean value, so you might just as well put `!empty($_POST)` insted of `count($_POST)`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this :D. !empty is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Change the offending line to `if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) _POST['unrelated_variable'] = 42;`. If this does not help, then you can rule out any warning-related issues, leaving setting values on `$_POST` as the only possible culprit.
2. Change your design so that you do not need to do direct writes on `$_POST` which many, myself included, consider a very bad idea.

Comment: I changed the offending line to the one you wrote (there is a $ missing). Same behaviour (browser tries to download file). So its not the name of the variables but the number of POST variables I guess. As I updated in the question, the server sends a "HTTP continue" response which I don't know how to handle. What does it mean?

Comment: @JP19: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html. What `100 Continue` means is really what the web server decided it means... so not much help there.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Also, the reason I am using POST is this is only a "relay" script (in which I want to transfer the client POSTED data, among other info, to the server). So with the hope of being efficient (not copy POST variables to another array), I just hacked and added these 2 POST variables.